# Problem with NPX create-react-app. Keeps getting stuck at "Found 0 Vulnerabilties"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

So I am trying to create a new React project using npx create-react-project but it keeps getting stuck after downloading the packages. So far the folder only contains the node modules and the 2 package.json files. The create-react-app goes well until it reaches found 0 vulnerabilities. I have done this in different folders and different hard drives but the same result. It just doesn't go further.

I also deleted my previous global create-react-app installation but this didn't make a difference either.

[image: Error pic of my Command Prompt]

**NPM Version**: 6.14.4

**Node Version**: v12.16.2

My package.json file only contains the following: 
`{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}`

**SOLUTION FOR ME: ** I Disabled my Anti-Virus and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

and then create a new app.

Also, you need to install git before run npx:

```
sudo apt install git
```

Comment: Nope, same result. It is stuck on the same spot again. Also I forgot to mention in my initial question that when I check the package.json file, it only has:
`{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}`

Comment: did you run exact command?  this command is not project related. It says to update npm??

Comment: I mean, I ran that command and there were some new npm packages added on and it finished normally after that.

But when i ran the npx create-react-app command, that did not work and it got stuck on found 0 vulnerabilities again.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the terminal where stuck? It will help someone to identify the problem

Comment: have you installed git in machine?

Comment: Yes I have. I currently have git version: 2.26.0.windows.1

Comment: My friend, the issue was my anti-virus. I disabled it and it worked :(